# Background-image scale on hover - not smooth everytime

Tags: css

I have a simple div where I hover to increase the background image size.

It works, apart from if I move mouse in and out quickly, sometimes the image jerks as opposed to smoothly growing and shrinking again.

This is the CSS:

```
.block__left {
            background: url("http://tpwd.texas.gov/state-parks/big-bend-ranch/gallery/Big-Bend-Ranch-Camping-_U8E2700.jpg") no-repeat;
            background-position: right -500px bottom -30px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 600px;
            -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1); 
            -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
            transform: scale(1, 1);
            -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
        }
.block__left:hover {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1); 
            -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
            transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
        }
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qgx37ked/1/)

**The question is: How to make it smooth every time?**

I'm testing in Chrome.

Comment: As you haven't used *cross browser css* for the `transition` n `transform` property that can be the reason otherwise its working fine for both *FF* as well as *Chrome*.

Comment: I use scss and a preprocessor with outo-prefix so that's not the issue

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
.block__left {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: That makes no difference unfortunately